# Blazor server issue with nested DI objects' scope

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-server-side, lifetime

I have been using Blazor for a few months now, and got use to when and how components render and re-rendered.

I however am struggling with scopes of DI injected objects inside other DI injected objects.

I am using .NET6 and Blazor Server with `render-mode="Server"`

The particular example I have is as follows:

A service registered as a Singleton, as I want to be able to query instances of the `IMkiiHardwareCommunication` in ANY component.

```cs
public class DeviceRepositoryGroup
{
    public Dictionary<string, IMkiiHardwareCommunication> MkiiDevices { get; }

    public void AddDevice<T>(string ipAddress, T device)
        where T : class
    {
        MkiiDevices.Add(ipAddress, device);
    }

    public void RemoveDevice(string ipAddress)
    {
        MkiiDevices.Remove(ipAddress);
    }

    public void ClearAllDevices()
    {
        MkiiDevices ??= new ();
        MkiiDevices.Clear();
    }
}
```

And then the `IMkiiHardwareCommunication` interface describes all members required to communicate with a Mkii Device. Several lines have been omitted for brevity:

```cs
public interface IMkiiHardwareCommunication : IAsyncDisposable
{
    Guid Id { get; }

    bool IsConnected { get; }

    string? IpAddress { get; set; }

    Task Connect(CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    Task Disconnect();
}


public class MkiiHardwareCommunication : IMkiiHardwareCommunication
{
    public Guid Id { get; }

    public bool IsConnected {get; private set; }

    public string? IpAddress { get; set; }

    public MkiiHardwareCommunication()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        IpAddress = "10.0.0.1"
        Console.WriteLine($"Created new MKII Instance with ID: {Id}");
    }

    Task Connect(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Code to connect
        IsConnected = true;
    }

    Task Disconnect()
    {
        // Code to disconnect
        IsConnected = false;
    }
    
    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Disposed the MKII with ID: {Id}");
        try
        {
            if (IsConnected)
            {
                await Disconnect();
            }

            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

}
```

All services are registered as follows:

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMkiiHardwareCommunication, MkiiHardwareCommunication>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<DeviceRepositoryGroup>();
```

Adding the instances are shown below. This is done on a standalone .razor page. The loop is introduced to simulate more than one device being added, please ignore the duplicate IP Address being added.

```
@page "/DeviceManager"

@inject IDeviceRepositoryGroup deviceRepositoryGroup

@while (deviceRepositoryGroup.MkiiDevices.Count() < 2)
{
    // I would expect to have 2 different instances, as it is registered as Transient.
    @inject IMkiiHardwareCommunication hardwareCommunication
                
    hardwareCommunication.IpAddress = IpAddressFromUI;
    deviceRepositoryGroup.AddDevice(hardwareCommunication.IpAddress, hardwareCommunication);
}
```

Now, when I eventually want to access the `MkiiHardwareCommunication` instance in a .razor component, I do the following every time:

```
@page "/"

<h1>@HardwareCommunication.IsConnected</h1>

@code {
    [Inject]
    public IDeviceRepositoryGroup DeviceRepositoryGroup { get; set; }

    public IMkiiHardwareCommunication? HardwareCommunication
    {
        get => DeviceRepositoryGroup.MkiiDevices[IpAddressFromUI];
    }
}
```

The first time navigating to the page requesting the `MkiiHardwareCommunication` instance (In this case the '/' page), nothing funny happens, I get the instance as it was added in the `DeviceManager` page.

However, as soon as I manually refresh the page (F5), the console's output indicates that the instance has been disposed. This then disconnects the device. I can however still use the instance, I would just need to connect again (which I do not want to do, I want it to keep its connection state).

I suspect I do not know enough of the lifetimes of objects that are nested inside other objects with their own lifetimes, because the `DeviceRepositoryGroup` instance is not disposed on page refresh, so I would have thought that the `Dictionary<string, IMkiiHardwareCommunication>` would keep all `IMkiiHardwareCommunication` instances in scope, for as long as the `DeviceRepositoryGroup` instance is in scope.

What am I missing here? Is there a way I can make the `IMkiiHardwareCommunication` scope the same as the `DeviceRepositoryGroup` instance's scope?

Comment: This is definitely not the purpose of transient services to survive as long as a singleton service. Try replacing your transient services by simple objects? I don't think you need IMkiiHardwareCommunication to be a service.

Comment: Agree with @T.Trassoudaine above.  This is definitely not how to use services. However, before I suggest anything in an answer, you define IDeviceRepositoryGroup but you haven't shown how you set it up in services, and you add `DeviceCommunicationManager` as a singleton but show no other reference to it.  Are you using a service for `IMkiiHardwareCommunication` for abstraction?

Comment: I have updated the question to show the correct service registration, thank you @MrCakaShaunCurtis.
I am only using the ``IMkiiHardwareCommunication`` as abstraction, as I do not want to new up the MkiiHardwareCommunication every time throughout my application, seeing I can have multiple of these devices.

So I should rather just insatiate the objects manually and then populate the Dictionary with the manual instances? Would this not suffer the same scope issues if the DeviceRepositoryGroup news up these instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach would work if you did not need to implement  `IDisposable` or `IAsyncDisposable` on your objects.  Normally Transient services are create and forget.  The SPA instance Scoped container in the Blazor Hub session creates the instance and hands it over, maintaining no reference to it.  But with disposable instances, someone needs to run dispose on the object.  That job is done by the Scoped DI container itself when it is destroyed.  To do that the container maintains a list of all the disposable objects it creates.

What happens in your code is when you hit F5 you are resetting the Hub session.  As part of the clear up process the Scoped DI container runs disposal on your transient objects.

As you maintain a reference to the object in the Singleton service the garbage collector doesn't remove it, but `DisposeAsync` has been run.

This is one approach (I haven't tested the code so there may be some typos, etc..).

1. Create your `IMkiiHardwareCommunication` instances when you need them, and then add them to the service.
2. Implement dispose in the service.

```
public class DeviceRepositoryGroup 
    : IAsyncDisposable
{
    // make sure you always have a dictionary
    public Dictionary<string, IMkiiHardwareCommunication> MkiiDevices { get; } = new Dictionary<string, IMkiiHardwareCommunication>();

    // Define TDevice needs to implement the IMkiiHardwareCommunication interface
    public void AddDevice<TDevice>(string ipAddress, TDevice device) where TDevice : IMkiiHardwareCommunication
        => MkiiDevices.Add(ipAddress, device);

    public async ValueTask RemoveDeviceAsync(string ipAddress)
    {
        var device = MkiiDevices[ipAddress];
        if (device != null)
        {
            await device.DisposeAsync();
            MkiiDevices.Remove(ipAddress);
        }
    }

    public async ValueTask ClearAllDevicesAsync()
    {
        foreach (var item in MkiiDevices)
        {
            await item.Value.DisposeAsync();
        }
        MkiiDevices.Clear();
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        => await this.ClearAllDevicesAsync();
}

// Fixes the type of IMkiiHardwareCommunication at Instantiation
public class DeviceRepositoryGroup<TDevice> 
    : IAsyncDisposable
     where TDevice : IMkiiHardwareCommunication
{
    // make sure you always have a dictionary
    public Dictionary<string, TDevice> MkiiDevices { get; } = new Dictionary<string, TDevice>();

    // Define TDevice needs to implement the IMkiiHardwareCommunication interface
    public void AddDevice(string ipAddress, TDevice device)
        => MkiiDevices.Add(ipAddress, device);

    public async ValueTask RemoveDeviceAsync(string ipAddress)
    {
        var device = MkiiDevices[ipAddress];
        if (device != null)
        {
            await device.DisposeAsync();
            MkiiDevices.Remove(ipAddress);
        }
    }

    public async ValueTask ClearAllDevicesAsync()
    {
        foreach (var item in MkiiDevices)
        {
            await item.Value.DisposeAsync();
        }
        MkiiDevices.Clear();
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        => await this.ClearAllDevicesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I could not understand why the DisposeAsync has been called, but the Singleton service still has a reference to the transient service, this clears it up.

I used your suggestion to implement the Factory pattern, where the factory is then also registered as a singleton. The Factory is then responsible for calling the DisposeAsync on all the objects.